# How to Generate Standard Attribute Setters for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have many strings in my application's models, each should not contain any leading, trailing and duplicate blanks.

In order to ensure this, I created separate attribute setter methods for each attribute:

```
def label=( text )
  write_attribute( :label, text.strip.squeeze(' '))
end

def description=( text )
  write_attribute( :description, text.strip.squeeze(' '))
end

...
```

There should be a more elegant, DRYer way. Including a check for nil.

Answer (score 1):

Define a class method in your concerns which creates all needed attribute setters. This version will return nil for all blank values, or the trimmed and squeezed string for others:

```
module ApplicationModel
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods

    def set_trimmed( *attributes )
      attributes.each do |a|
        define_method "#{ a.to_s }=" do |t|
          tt = t.blank? ? nil : t.strip.squeeze(' ')
          write_attribute( a, tt )
        end
      end
    end

  end
end
```

and simply list the attributes in your model for which you want this attribute setter to be defined (don't forget to include the module above):

```
include ApplicationModel

set_trimmed :label, :description, :postal_address, :street_address, ...
```